# Side effect of one meta function to another meta function in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

yesterday I came across a problem, where my metafunction didn't work as exspected.
Then I commented out all (seemingly) unrelated code to find the problem. And it worked.

Here is my code complete code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename...> struct make_void { using type = void; };

template <typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;

template <typename Functor, typename = void>
struct is_functor : std::false_type {};

template <typename Functor>
struct is_functor<Functor, void_t<decltype(&Functor::operator())>>
    : std::true_type {};

template <typename Callable,
          typename Signature = decltype(&Callable::operator())>
struct ExtractCallableRunTypeImpl;

template <typename Callable, typename R, typename... Args>
struct ExtractCallableRunTypeImpl<Callable, R (Callable::*)(Args...) const> {
  using Type = R(Args...);
};

template <typename Callable>
using ExtractCallableRunType =
    typename ExtractCallableRunTypeImpl<Callable>::Type;

template <typename Functor, typename SFINAE = void>
struct IsConvertibleToRunType : std::false_type {};

template <typename Callable>
struct IsConvertibleToRunType<Callable, void_t<decltype(&Callable::operator())>>
    : std::is_convertible<Callable, ExtractCallableRunType<Callable> *> {};


int main() {
  auto f = []() {};
  std::cout << IsConvertibleToRunType<decltype(f)>::value << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Running this code will print "0". 
After commenting out the following portion of the code, it shows my expected behavior and prints out "1".

```
template <typename Functor, typename = void>
struct is_functor : std::false_type {};

template <typename Functor>
struct is_functor<Functor, void_t<decltype(&Functor::operator())>>
    : std::true_type {};
```

It seems to be somehow related to the use of void_t, but frankly can't wrap my head around why it has any influence on the code following. The is_functor metafunction is not used at all.

Here the demo http://rextester.com/JRQU76860
Run the demo, then comment out the marked portion of the code and run again.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb89f8f0676bb231)

Comment: I'm using the visual studio compiler.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 (v140).

Comment: This reproduces it http://rextester.com/JRQU76860

Comment: I once had a very similar bug. Using nested decltype and void_t, and changing template parameter names seemed to help.

Comment: `void_t<Functor, decltype(&Functor::operator())>` seems to do the trick

Comment: Works, thanks! And of course thank you for the valuable finding that this shouldn't be necessary, it only is because of a bug in vs 15.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907885